# Redirect route link instead of rendering component inline

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a `/A/B/B.ts` component and I can create route link to it in root component using `<a href="" [routeLink]="['ABLink']">A - B</a>` and `<router-outlet>`. The problem is the content of the component is rendered inline and I want it to redirect just like a regular link. When I try Open in New Tab on the link, I get a `404 not found` error for `localhost/A/B` path. What should I do?

[Sample plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/64aa0UpwrqB1dDvDhLFB?p=preview)

If you click "Role Search" it works fine but if you right click and select Open in New Window you get a 404 error.

Comment: Please provide more details. For me it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What do you mean by "the content of the component is rendered inline"? Do you use `HashLocationStrategy` or `PushLocationStrategy` (default)?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: added plnkr page.